# How do I test a trigger script using update with inserted table, I get the error "Invalid object name 'inserted"

Tags: sql

I want to be able to write a unit test script that will show the results of each statement in the code. When I run a script using the inserted table, the message displays "Invalid object name 'inserted'". The only way I found to test the logic now is to use the source table to test the code, and then change from the source table to the inserted when I create the trigger. This would be used as a control to promote code to qa and production. What is the best way to write a unit test script for triggers with inserted tables?
sql server 2008r

```
--insert test
INSERT INTO SIS.dbo.People (First_Name,Middle_Name,Last_Name)
SELECT
     T.ForeName
    ,T.Middle_Name
    ,T.Surname
FROM CRM.dbo.Contact1 C
INNER JOIN SIS.dbo.People P
    ON P.People_ID = C.Key4
CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(C.Contact) T
WHERE C.Key1 = '76'

--insert reference inserted table
INSERT INTO SIS.dbo.People (First_Name,Middle_Name,Last_Name)
SELECT
     T.ForeName
    ,T.Middle_Name
    ,T.Surname
FROM inserted i --change to inserted
INNER JOIN SIS.dbo.People P
    ON P.People_ID = i.Key4
CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(i.Contact) T
WHERE i.Key1 = '76'
```

Comment: You'll need to use an `OUTPUT` clause on the first `INSERT`. In that `OUTPUT` clause, `inserted` will be a "magic" table that will exist only there. But you can use it to output into a table variable. In the second insert, you can insert from that table variable.

Comment: ok, i created a insertedcontact test table to use for my code, i'll try the output clause